# Find the consumer surplus, given supply and demand equations

Tags: calculus, economics

> Find the Consumer Surplus, given the demand and supply equations $$ D(x)=\frac{405}{\sqrt{x}} $$
>   $$ S(x)=5\sqrt{x} $$
>   The equilibrium point is $(81,45)$.

I know the formula for [consumer surplus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_surplus#Calculation_from_supply_and_demand), but I am stuck on finding the integral of 
$405/\sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For context, I grabbed this picture from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_surplus#Calculation_from_supply_and_demand)

[image: surplus]

The red area is the integral of $D(x) - 45$ from $0$ to $81$. Namely,
$$
\int_0^{81} \left(\frac{405}{\sqrt{x}}-45\right)\,dx
$$ 
To integrate, write $405/\sqrt{x}$ as $x^{-1/2}$ and use the formula $\int x^a = x^{a+1}/(a+1)$.

To check the answer, you can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%28405%2Fsqrt%28x%29-45%29+from+0+to+81): it's $3645$.

Answer (score 2):

**Point of Equilibrium for Supply and Demand**

$$ D(q_e)=S(q_e) $$
$$ \frac{405}{\sqrt{q_e}}=5\sqrt{q_e} $$
$$ 405=5|q_e|$$
$$ |q_e|=\frac{405}{5}=81$$
The next step is to find the market price, which is
$$ P_{mkt}(q_e)=D(q_e)=S(q_e)=5\sqrt{81}=5\cdot 9=45 $$
Therefore, the point of equilibrium is
$$ (q_e, P_{mkt}(q_e))=(81, 45)$$
**Consumer Surplus**

By definition the consumer surplus $CS$, is the area between the demand curve and the market price from $0$ to the quantity at the point of equilibrium. Mathematically this is expressed as
$$ CS= \int_{0}^{q_e} D(q) - P_{mkt}(q_e)\ dq $$
So in this case we have, 
$$ CS= \int_{0}^{81} \frac{405}{\sqrt{q}} - 45\ dq $$
$$= 405\int_{0}^{81} q^{-\frac{1}{2}}dq- 45\int_0^{81} dq $$
$$= 405\left[\frac{q^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\frac12}\right]_{0}^{81} - 45(81-0)$$
$$= 2(405)(\sqrt{81}-0)- 45(81-0)$$
$$= 2(405)(9)- 45(81) $$
$$=7290-3645=3645 $$

Comment: I have that part done, but im stuck on finding the consumer surplus. Right now I am trying to find (405/sqrt(x))dx

Comment: You know what I'm saying?

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii I was agreeing that what he answered was correct

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii, that's why it's called a hint. By the way, his equilibrium point wasn't posted when I posted it.

Comment: After that step would it be: [405(81)^(-1/2)-405(0)^(-1/2)]-3645?

Comment: or is the answer just 3645?

Comment: @Ben, yes the answer is 3645. I took the total area under the curve of D and subtracted the area of the rectangle PQ. The formula isn't necessary when you understand integrals.